# 2sxc blog app posts and DNN search

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

While using the 2sxc blog app, i noticed that the DNN search results shows all the post but the link of the post title is the main Blog page and not the actual post link.

**Example search results show:**

*Page title:*
I am a post title

*Link for the above title is:* 
/blog

*When it should be:*
/blog/post/i-am-a-post-title

Managed to modify the search result by adding the following to the cshtml code:

```
@using ToSic.Eav.DataSources
@using ToSic.SexyContent.Search
@using DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules

@functions{

    // Prepare the data - get all categories through the pipeline

    public override void CustomizeData()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>

    /// Populate the search - ensure that each entity has an own url/page

    /// </summary>

    /// <param name="searchInfos"></param>

    /// <param name="moduleInfo"></param>

    /// <param name="startDate"></param>

    public override void CustomizeSearch(Dictionary<string, List<ISearchInfo>> searchInfos, ModuleInfo moduleInfo, DateTime startDate)
    {

        foreach (var si in searchInfos["Default"])
        {
            si.QueryString = "post=" + si.Entity.EntityId;
        }
    }
}
```

But rather than  **si.Entity.EntityId** i want the **UrlKey** to show, any idea to how to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple - just convert to a DynamicEntity - https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/DotNet-DynamicEntity:

```
    foreach (var si in searchInfos["Default"])
    {
        si.QueryString = "post=" + AsDynamic(si.Entity).UrlKey;
    }
```

Love from Switzerland :)
PS: Pls mark as answered if this fixed your issue

Comment: Still unable to get UrlKey :(

Comment: Awesome, loving Switzerland and 2sxc module :)

Comment: Note: found out that it currently only indexes page 1 see https://github.com/2sic/app-blog/issues/5

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var si in AsDynamic(searchInfos["Default"]))
    {
        si.QueryString = "post=" + si.UrlKey;
    }
```

After making the searchInfo to be a dynamic entity, property like "Title" works. But the property "UrlKey" doesn't work.